# PHP continue statement

Tags: php, continue

When reading a PHP book I wanted to try my own (continue) example.
I made the following code but it doesn't work although everything seems to be ok

```
$num2 = 1;

    while ($num2 < 19)
        {
            if ($num2 == 15) { 
            continue; 
            } else {
            echo "Continue at 15 (".$num2.").<br />";
            $num2++;
            }

        }
```

The output is

```
Continue at 15 (1).
Continue at 15 (2).
Continue at 15 (3).
Continue at 15 (4).
Continue at 15 (5).
Continue at 15 (6).
Continue at 15 (7).
Continue at 15 (8).
Continue at 15 (9).
Continue at 15 (10).
Continue at 15 (11).
Continue at 15 (12).
Continue at 15 (13).
Continue at 15 (14).

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/php/continueandbreak.php on line 20
```

Line 20 is that line

```
if ($num2 == 15) {
```

Would you please tell me what's wrong with my example ?
I am sorry for such a Noob question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you don't increment `$num2` before the `continue` you will get into an infinite loop;

```
$num2 = 0;

while ($num2 < 18)
    {
            $num2++;
            if ($num2 == 15) { 
              continue; 
            } else {
              echo "Continue at 15 (".$num2.").<br />";
            }


    }
```

Comment: Your code will still infinite loop; `continue` starts the next iteration of the loop without executing what comes after the if-else clause.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need continue there, your code equivalent to;

```
$num2 = 1;
while ($num2 < 19){
    if ($num2 != 15) { 
        echo "Continue at 15 (".$num2.").<br />";
        $num2++;
    }
}
```

If that's not what you're trying to achieve, you're using continue wrong.

Comment: This achieves the same result: an infinite loop that will eventually time out.

Comment: You definitely want to move $num2++; outside the if loop (below)

Answer (score 0):

in php, use **foreach** for arrays and **for** for looping

```
for($num = 1; $num < 19; $num++) {
    if ($num != 15) { 
       echo "Continue at 15 (" . $num . ") . <br />";
       break;
    }   
}
```